# regex starts with '_' and ends with white space/new line in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to be able to locate this pattern `'_*'`
meaning starts with `'_'` and ends with either a white space or a new line.

also I have another regex to locate a word of capital letters only: `[A-Z]+`
is this accurate, or there's a better way of writing it?

I use Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as `[A-Z]+` goes, it will work with latin input. So will `\p{Upper}+`

If you need to support a wider character set, consider `\p{Lu}+` which will match any upper case unicode character.

Pattern's javadoc is good! http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

If you try

```
String _command = "AFTER_2011/03/01 GREATER_2004";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("_\\S+");
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(_command);
while(matcher.find()) {
    String name = _command.substring(matcher.start()+1, matcher.end());
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

it prints

```
2011/03/01
2004
```

EDIT: As @Alan Moore suggests you can do the following.

```
String _command = "AFTER_2011/03/01 GREATER_2004";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("_(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(_command);
while(matcher.find()) {
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the correct regex, but if you really need to strip the leading underscore, why not use `"_(\\S+)"` and retrieve the captured text with `m.group(1)`?

Comment: @Alan Moore, Thank you for the suggestion. I have added this as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_.*(\\s|\\n)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(_command);

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) {
  // Get the matching string
  String match = matcher.group();
}
```

`[A-Z]+` is fine

If you want code too let me know

Comment: `\s` already matches `\n`, so `(\s|\n)` is just less efficient way to match `\s`.  And it still won't find a match at the end of the string like @Peter's solution does.

Answer (score -1):

If regex is `_.*(\s|\n)` using Java, you'll have to write the same as `_.*(\\s|\\n)`

**Update**:

Resulting groups are those parts of the regex within brackets. So currently get only the last space or line break.

Try with this regex:

`(_.*\\s+)`

Comment: `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f\v]`, so matching `\n` or `\r` in addition to `\s` is pointless.  Also, the OP is trying to locate matches within a larger string, so the anchors (`^` and `$`) are inappropriate.

Comment: The point was just to show the backslash duplication in Java. The initial regex was inspired from another answer. True it's not very precise. I'll update.